# Prolog - How to get the sum of a list's elements?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm very new to prolog and I am trying to write a little program that, given a list, returns the sum of the list's elements. Following all the examples I've seen led me to a solution that looks like this:

```
addup([],0).
addup([FirstNumber | RestOfList], Total) :-
    addup(RestOfList, TotalOfRest),
    Total is FirstNumber + TotalOfRest.
```

But when I test that solution with these values:

```
?- addup([1,2,3,4],0).
```

I just get garbage values from it like _34521.

Then I tried a second solution that looks like this:

```
sum([], 0).
sum([H|T], N):-
    X is H+N,
    sum(T, X).
```

This one is able to add up the numbers correctly, but it is unable to pass the final value of X, which is the true answer, into N. So for the test case:

```
?- sum([1,2,3,4], 0).
```

I get an answer of 6, the final value of N, and the second-to-last value of X, instead of 10, the final value of X. Any help and/or explanations of why neither of these solutions work would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is not_number?

Comment: Whoops, that was just an example I copied from somewhere else so I would know how to format the test case. It's fixed to show the correct function names now. Thank you.

Comment: Your first solution `addup/2` works just fine. `addup([1,2,3,4], S).` succeeds and produces `S = 10`, and `addup([1,2,3,4], 0).` says "no" or "false" - that is, it fails (in other words, sthe sum is not 0). So I don't see what the problem is. Note that the second argument represents the sum. `addup/2` is a Prolog predicate, and predicates don't *return* values. They succeed or the fail (or they don't terminate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the sum of an empty list is 0 - this is the base case, which you already had.

Secondly, the sum `N` of an element `H` and a list `T` is the sum of the list `T` added to `H`. Prolog operates on unification, so this says that `N` is unified with the sum of `H` and `T`, where the sum of `T` is unified with `X` using `sum(T,X)`.

```
sum([], 0).
sum([H|T], N):-
    sum(T, X),
    N is X + H.
```

This gives:

```
?- sum([1,2,3,4],N).
N = 10.
```

In your original question, `?- sum([1,2,3,4], 0).` actually says "this is true if the sum of the list `[1,2,3,4]` is `0`" - you need to pass a variable as the second argument to `sum` to be unified with the answer.

**Further information:**

`_34521` is a representation of an unbound variable - this says that there is a variable, but that it has not yet been unified with a value.

**Secondary consideration:**

For a suitably long list, the implementation above will run out of stack space, as each frame of the recursion must be stored, so that the addition can happen from the bottom up. In order to prevent a stack error, we can use a tail-recursive accumulator like so:

```
sum(L, N):-
    sum(L, 0, N).

sum([],N,N).
sum([H|T],A,N) :-
    A1 is A + H,
    sum(T,A1,N).
```

... which retains the signature of the original method, wrapping sum/3. As there is no choice-point in the body of the rule (given that A + H is always the same for a given A and H, and the list is either empty or not), Prolog will discard each frame as it leaves scope (as there is nothing more to be done with it) and, on completion, will return to the original caller.

Simplified stack for `sum([1,2,3],N)` in each instance:

non-tail-recursive:

```
rest-of-stack
rest-of-stack,sum([1|[2,3]],_1001)
rest-of-stack,sum([1|[2,3]],_1001),sum([2|[3]],_1002)
rest-of-stack,sum([1|[2,3]],_1001),sum([2|[3]],_1002),sum([3|[]],_1003)
rest-of-stack,sum([1|[2,3]],_1001),sum([2|[3]],_1002),sum([3|[]],_1003),sum([],0)
rest-of-stack,sum([1|[2,3]],_1001),sum([2|[3]],_1002),sum([3|[]],3)
rest-of-stack,sum([1|[2,3]],_1001),sum([2|[3]],5)
rest-of-stack,sum([1|[2,3]],6)
rest-of-stack
```

tail-recursive:

```
rest-of-stack
rest-of-stack,sum([1,2,3],_1001)
rest-of-stack,sum([1|[2,3]],0,_1001)
rest-of-stack,sum([2|[3]],1,_1001)
rest-of-stack,sum([3|[]],3,_1001)
rest-of-stack,sum([],6,6)
rest-of-stack
```

Note that the tail-recursive stack has a limited depth for any length of list (dependent on what is calling it), where the non-tail-recursive stack goes to a depth directly proportional to the length of the list.

Thus, a call such as `N is 10^7,length(L,N),maplist(=(1),L),sum(L,N).` (as raised by @false) will likely fail without tail-recursion, and likely succeed with it.

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you, I understand now!

Comment: Yet, `N is 10^7, length(L,N),maplist(=(1),L), sum(L,N).` produces an error - it should succeed.

Comment: @false With a large enough stack, it should succeed - the logic is sound. I assume, however, that you would prefer the tail-recursive accumulator method that I have just added?

Comment: @JimAshworth: Right, it's just about the resource consumption that could be constant. Even better would be a version using clpfd.

Comment: @false true, but this is a simple enough question that clpfd feels like overkill for someone just dipping a toe into Prolog (I learnt Prolog in a uni course back in 2014, and only found out about clpfd through SO a week or so ago)

Comment: @false Also, given that I only learnt about clpfd very recently, I'm not confident that I'd be able to give a "good" answer using clpfd

Comment: @Jim: No need to be confident! Try it!

Comment: I second what false says: Try it! For comparison (to what currently seems "overkill" to you): To me, what you posted seems extremely low-level and not doing justice to the true potential of a declarative Prolog solution.